# How to animate small water surfaces in structures?

Tags: modeling, fluid-simulation

I would like to model a so-called stormwater overflow (used within a sewage system) which is a concrete chamber in which the water level is rising during a storm inflow until the crest of an overflow weir is reached. Then, the water forms a small waterfall. I would like to have some waves on the water surface and one should see the water "falling down" at the overflow. It should look like this:

[image]

The use of the FluidSimulator of course would be straightforward, but it did not work properly in some first tests and was also very time-consuming. To complicate it a bit, the weir should be movable, going down while the water is overflowing, so there will be changing geometry.

So I ask whether there would be some way to "fake" the water. Ocean modifier plus some additional modifiers?

Greetings from Germany, Tschöbbel

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. This seems, as you already pointed out, a job for the fluid simulator. If you don't want to use it, try to describe which kind of effects you may be allowed to give up. Also a quick scketch of the animation would be useful to clealy understand the situation.

Answer (score 7):

### Final:

[image: final]

You can fake it pretty easily with creative **UV Mapping** and animating **Texture location**. I've used **Noise Texture** for it as a **Bump** for **Principled BSDF**.

Let's break it down.

### Mesh:

It's simple **Plane** with one edge **Beveled**. Nothing to add here.

[image: Mesh]

### Material:

We need to add material first, it will be easier during **UV Mapping**.

Again, nothing to fancy here.

[image: material]

**Animating.**

X value in **Mapping** node will be animated - in this example keyframes are on frame 1 with value 0 and on frame 60 with value 1. In your case axis could be different, also bigger difference between values will give faster animation.

After adding keyframes you should go to **Dope Sheet** editor, select both frames from X axis and choose **Key > Interpolation Mode > Linear**.

### UV Mapping:

Go to **Edit Mode**, **Select All** and <kbd>U</kbd> > **Unwrap**.

[image: uv_1]

Now changing X axis value in **Mapping** node should give as something like this (I'm using **Node Wrangler** to be able to see **Color Ramp** node output):

[image: uv_2]

Go back to **UV Image Editor**, select faces where water should be flowing faster, enable **Proportional Editing** and scale them down along X axis as much as you want.

[image: uv_3]

### Final thoughts:

This is basic overview for the water flow. You should also add some Particle system for the splashing water and maybe some foam texture. I think those should be another questions otherwise this one could become to big/tutorial like answer. Or just search trough the web, there are plenty tutorials about this.

Comment: Wow! This is exactly the effect I would li

Comment: Sorry, I fight with some issues of my smartphone, maybe something was double.    Wow! Dear Luke, this is exactly the effect I would like to obtain. Thank you very much for your very detailed answer! I will try that out within the next days.  -  Greetings, Tschöbbel

Comment: @Tschöbbel I will also try to experiment with foam texture and particles and maybe add this as a simple overview with blend file included.

Comment: I just tried your proposal and I was successful at the first try! Thanks again for your good description.

Comment: After browsing through some other questions relating to "water" in this forum, I got the idea to use a procedural texture as displacement texture (UV coordinates, normal) for a highpoly water surface using the Displace modifier in order to get real geometry (no high waves, just a bit). With a simple Voronoi texture, this works well. Is there some way to animate the textures used by a Displace modifier? One idea is perhaps to make an animated bitmap as a movie? Or is there a possibility to use the output of your bump texture with animated coordinates as continuously varying displacement map?